# A problem when converting string to date in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How to convert NSString 2010-08-03 04:37:31.0 to August 3, 2010?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate but `NSDateFormatter` is what you are looking for.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inDateString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd',' yyyy"];
NSString *outDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

There are two problems with this approach though.

1. The input string is that it lacks timezone data
2. Different cultures expect a different order than Month Day Year. That can be fixed if you use one of the generic `NSDateFormatterStyle` formats like `NSDateFormatterLongStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.  You probably want a format string of `@"%B %e, %Y"` for the output.